# Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session in VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, session-id

I am facing this error in Visual Studio Code after authorizing an org with session id:

> INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal
> Session. Session not found, missing session hash:
> 5E2HBAWoYi5SzBUZbJpm8BDlRmKRR5IKWLQ8VdWS4zI= This error usually occurs
> after a session expires or a user logs out. Decoder:
> DataInDbSessionKeyDecoder

This works fine when the session is active and I can retrieve and deploy but after the session expires, I get this error and it is not fixed by reauthorizing the org with a new session id. The only way to solve this for now is to create a new project (losing all the files) and then authorize which I do not want to do everyday. Kindly request help on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just removing authorization and re-logging wont help.

1. Log out of org.
2. restart system
3. authorize org again.

Should go smoothly. I have found this problem to be common when you share access for the same salesforce user.

Comment: This is such a great reminder. It seemed simple but saved so much headache. I had updated the sfdx cli and fixed the network issue but it was still giving me an error when it said connection successful. But then I saw this and restarted vs code and it worked.